# Logic proofs - Satisfiability

Tags: logic, proof-verification, satisfiability

I need some help with some logic proofs. There are some questions that ask for the satisfiability of a formula and others that ask if the equivalence or consequence is true or false. ¿Are my answers correct?

**Check Satisfiability**

$$
\forall X p(X) \rightarrow \exists X \neg p(X)
$$
Invalid
$$
\forall X p(X) \vee \forall X \neg p(X)
$$
Invalid

**True or false questions**
$$
\exists X \exists Y q(X,Y) \models \exists X q(X,X)
$$
False
$$
\exists Y \forall X q(X,Y) \models \forall X \exists Y q(X,Y)
$$
True
$$
\forall X p(X) \rightarrow \forall X q(X) \models \exists X ( p(X) \rightarrow q(X) )
$$
True
$$
\forall X (p(X) \rightarrow q(X) \equiv \exists X p(X) \rightarrow \forall X q(X)
$$
False
$$
\exists X(p(X) \rightarrow q(X)) \equiv \forall X p(X) \rightarrow \exists X q(X)
$$
True
$$
\exists X( p(X,Y) \vee q(X) ) \equiv \exists X p(X,Y) \vee \exists X q(X)
$$
True

Answer (score 0):

Take care about satisfiability vs validity. The first two formulas are not valid, however it is asked whether they are satisfiable. In a model where $p(X)$ is false for all elements $x$ both formulas evaluate to true, thus they are satisfiable.

Moreover, take a look at

> $\exists Y \forall X q(X,Y) \models \forall X \exists Y q(X,Y)$

You cannot arbitrarily switch the quantifiers since the premise talks only about one element Y, while in the conclusion Y depends on X.

Comment: I agree with your answer for the first two ones, they are satisfiable but not valid. However I think $$\exists Y \forall X q(X,Y) \models \forall X \exists Y q(X,Y)$$  is correct, they are not equivalent because as you said the quantifiers cannot be switched arbitrarily but it is true that the second one is logic consecuence of the first one.